# Distributed Tracing with Service Bus Triggered Function

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, distributed-tracing

According to the docs around [distributed tracing for Servicebus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2), the `Diagnostic-Id` property should be used to store the WC3 `traceparent`.

When an Azure Function is triggered via a service bus message, I would expect this value to be used to initialize the `tracecontext` (so AppInsight logs would get tagged with the appropriate `operation_Id`).

I've even tried to copy it over to the tracecontext and it doesn't seem to work.

Is it not possible to maintain distributed tracing with Service Bus in Azure functions?

### Update

You can kinda of get this to work by implementing the wrapped app insights context, however, calls to `context.log` will still have the original `traceparent` reference :(

```
export default async function contextPropagatingHttpTrigger(context, req) {
  // overwrite with the proper traceparent from the incoming SB message. 
  const sbTraceParent = context.bindingData.applicationProperties['diagnostic-Id'];
  if (sbTraceParent) {
    context.traceContext.traceparent = sbTraceParent;
  }

  const correlationContext = appInsights.startOperation(context, req) as CorrelationContext;

  // Wrap the Function runtime with correlationContext
  return appInsights.wrapWithCorrelationContext(async () => {
    const startTime = Date.now(); // Start trackRequest timer

    try {
      // operation_Id matches SB 'diagnostic-Id'
      appInsights.defaultClient.trackTrace({
        message: 'Correct Trace Context',
      });

      // operation_Id is the original function traceparent
      context.log('Incorrect Trace Context');

      return await trigger(context, req);

    } catch (e) {
      context.log.error(e);
      throw e;
    } finally {
      // Track Request on completion
      appInsights.defaultClient.flush();
    }
  }, correlationContext)();
}
```